# How the activation function gets fired if all the biases and weights are zeros?

Tags: tensorflow

The following code is from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py). Under the comment "Create the model" there are lines

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

Can somebody tell me how the activation function ever gets fired if all the weights and biases are zeros?

Answer (score 0):

'Gets fired' just means being evaluated. Like if you have a function `f(x)` and know the value `x` you calculate the result. Evaluation function will always get fired if the function can be evaluated for this values.

For any `x, W, b` your function will get calculated so it will always get fired. The other thing is that the gradient will always be 0 and this network will not learn anything.

Comment: that's the problem,"this network will not learn anything".So what is the significance of putting all the weights and biases zeros.Why don't they put random numbers instead??